# Unknown WAV file format - SHA256

Tags: python, load, wav, sha256

I have a wave file given in an unknown format. When I opened it as a normal file with 'rb', I was able to access the contents. This is the contents:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:b9163de8b5ab5aa05d57dd8345111a0b19a83b5b91725bf6f00c53737936843c
size 347200
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get the audio signal contents from this?

Comment: That doesn’t look like a WAV file at all. Why did you think it is one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a direct link to a file in github LFS (large file storage)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219778/how-to-get-a-direct-link-to-a-file-in-github-lfs-large-file-storage)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think this solves the situation, it might actually be a pointer as described in your link. Thanks

Comment: The file was given as part of a dataset saying that it is a wav file. No other information was given.