# How to retrieve large csv file I stored on github

Tags: github, git-lfs

When I went into my github I had a csv file that I stored there that was large so I probably used `git lfs` to store it, but when I went back in the file all I see is this

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:d96f2a228ce88d533a77646d33e15be5ec00612db71332002f946611304d3234
size 651828087
```

Is there a way of retrieving this file I stored in its entirety?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219778/how-to-get-a-direct-link-to-a-file-in-github-lfs-large-file-storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pointer file used by Git LFS, which is stored in the repository in place of the actual large file and refers to it.  You'll see this in the repository if you don't have Git LFS installed or you haven't configured it properly.

In order to make Git LFS work automatically, install it, and then run `git lfs install`.  That will set up a set of filters such that when a repository contains LFS files, they're checked out automatically.

For existing repositories, you should be able to run `git lfs pull`, which should fetch the large files and then check them out in the working tree.